# Using HDF5DotNet in C#, how do I retrieve and access cell arrays from a .mat file

Tags: c#, hdf5, hdf

Using HDF5DotNet in C#, I'd like to read in a 900x1 Cell array, then access 2D double arrays inside of each cell. I found how to map an H5Array to an array in C# (See below), but I can't figure out how to map an H5Array if the array is made of "cells". The HDF5DotNet H5D.getType(...) function returns only an integer ID, that I can't seem to relate to anything of interest. I'm assuming that there is a class in HDF5DotNet that will coorespond to cells.

```
H5.Open();
var fileID = H5F.open("_mapCsvFiles/simdata_020_01.mat", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);

var datasetID = H5D.open(fileID, "B_map");
var dataSpace = H5D.getSpace(datasetID);
var size = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(dataSpace);
var dataType = H5D.getType(datasetID);

// What H5 Type would coorespond to CELLS
//????[,] dataArray = new ????[size[0], size[1]];
//var wrapArray = new H5Array<????>(dataArray);

double[,] dataArray = new double[size[0], size[1]];
var wrapArray = new H5Array<double>(dataArray);

H5D.read(datasetID, dataType, wrapArray);
```